# Why don't OpenGL functions use templates?

Tags: c++, function, templates, opengl

For exampe, if I wanted to clear the color buffer, I would have to call:

```
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color); //color is a float array of 4 numbers
```

But OpenGL also offers

```
glClearBufferiv(); //expects an int array
glClearBufferuiv(); //expects an unsigned int array
```

So why doesn't OpenGL use templates? Like so:

```
glClearBuffer<float>(...)
```

Comment: There is no need for templates. Function overloading would be enough. But C does not support that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because OpenGL is actually a C library, not C++. The reason you can use it in C++ is because one of the main design considerations in C++ is that it be able to use C code, but that comes with the inevitable circumstance that C APIs you use won't have nice C++ interfaces.

Comment: This also makes it easy to roll your own adapters, thin header file shims that prettify an interface, and engage in best practices (get variable length buffers into fized sized ones if they fit, and if not dynamically allocate, freeing iff you dynamically allocated -- doing that *everywhere* makes your code better, and you can do it in a C++ shim)

Comment: @Yakk Yes, exactly. It's effective, satisfying, and allows you to gain a more detailed understanding of the OpenGL API.